# Implode an array range in PHP

Tags: php, implode

Is there an easy way, preferably a one-liner, to implode an array range.

**Example:**

```
array(1,4,6,88,51,3,5,48,59,4);
```

In addition, how would I be able to implode between the first and the third value only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
implode(',', $range);
implode(',', array_slice($range, 0, 3));
```